# Shopify API Suddenly Failing with HTTP Status Code 429?

Tags: api, shopify, http-status-code-429

Our application, which uses the Shopify API to updata our store's product data and get order information, suddenly is getting failed requests a new response error code: 429 (snapshot of the headers of a request below). Has anyone experienced this?  What's the correct way to handle this error?  And (perhaps more importantly): Where do developers go to find out what changes are coming and when they'll be implemented, so we're not caught by surprise?

```
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 19 Dec 2012 15:58:37 GMT
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 429
Retry-After: 600
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Request-Id: ***********
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
Set-Cookie: _secure_session_id=*********; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
X-Runtime: 0.041736
HTTP-Status-Code: 429 HTTP/1.1 429
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From November 16th:

http://www.shopify.com/technology/6901970-api-update-status-code-change

You can follow that blog I guess if you want to know when they plan on changing things... sometimes the actual change takes longer than the initial working date. I think that is the case with 503 to 429.